# facebook comments with wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress

I've a wordpress blog for my website and added facebook comment for that. It shows the option to enter the comment using facebook account. But that doesn't show the comments from users.

Any idea about that will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin

```
facebook-comments-for-wordpress.3.1.3
```

only you have to write the following shortcode wherever you want comments to be displayed:

```
<?php if (function_exists('facebook_comments')) facebook_comments(); ?>
```

I have implemented it and it works fine.